# The link changes, but the contents don't change. What should I do?

Tags: reactjs

I don't know what the problem is. No matter how hard I look, I can't see the problem. Please help me! I used React-router.  The address of the link points to where I want to go, but the content inside is not what I wanted. The screen of "OpenChats" (the text that appears to be "오픈채팅") shows the same screen as the screen of "Chat" (the text that appears to be "채팅"). I want each screen to appear. The link is different, but why does the same screen appear? The content inside is different.

**Openchat Data file**

```
import React from "react";
import OpenChatPresenter from "./OpenChatPresenter";
-import image file-

const OpenChatContainer = () => {
  const title = {
    title: [
      "보더대마왕-보더콜리견주모임...",
      "경기도 보더콜리 모임 (타견종가···",
      "이름/27/지역/강아지이름",
    ],
  };
  const image = {
    src: [User, Open],
  };
  const content = {
    message: [
      "동영상을 보냈습니다.",
      "반갑습니다",
      "대화 중인 오픈채팅방이 없습니다.",
    ],
  };
  const time = {
    time: ["오후 11:01", "오전 11:29", "오후 06:36"],
  };
  const icons = {
    bell: [Bell, Bell, ""],
  };
  const member = {
    num: [78, 19, ""],
  };
  return (
    <OpenChatPresenter
      title={title}
      image={image}
      content={content}
      time={time}
      icons={icons}
      member={member}
    />
  );
};

export default OpenChatContainer;
```

**Openchat Presenter file**

```
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import ChatHeader from "../../Components/ChatHeader";

const OpenChatPresenter = ({ title, image, content, time, icons, member }) => {
  console.log(OpenChatPresenter);
  return (
    <Wrapper>
      <ChatHeader />

      {Object.values(title.title).map((title, i) => {
        return (
          <Profile>
            <div style={{ marginRight: "5px" }}>{title}</div>
            <span>{member.num[i]}</span>
            <img src={icons.pin[i]} alt="" />
            <img src={icons.bell[i]} alt="" />
            <ChatTime>{time.time[i]}</ChatTime>
          </Profile>
        );
      })}
    </Wrapper>
  );
};
export default OpenChatPresenter;
```

Chat files are similar to open chat files, but they are slightly different. However, the difference does not appear on the screen.

**Chat presenter file**

```
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import ChatHeader from "../../Components/ChatHeader";
import Ad from "../../Assets/images/ad.jpg";

const ChatsPresenter = ({ title, content, time, image, icons, member }) => {
  return (
    <Wrapper>
      <ChatHeader />
      <AdContainer>
        <img src={Ad} alt="" />
      </AdContainer>
      {Object.values(title.title).map((title, i) => {
        return (
          <Profile>
            <div style={{ display: "flex" }}>
              <ProfileImg src={image.src[i]} />
              <div>
                <MeChatContainer>
                  <div style={{ marginRight: "5px" }}>{title}</div>
                  <span>{member.num[i]}</span>
                  <img src={icons.pin[i]} alt="" />
                  <img src={icons.bell[i]} alt="" />
                </MeChatContainer>
                <MeChat>{content.message[i]}</MeChat>
              </div>
            </div>
            <ChatTime>{time.time[i]}</ChatTime>
          </Profile>
        );
      })}
    </Wrapper>
  );
};
export default ChatsPresenter;
```

**Chat data file**

```
import React from "react";
import ChatsPresenter from "./ChatPresenter";
-import image file-
const ChatContainer = () => {
  const title = {
    title: ["MEMO", "김은진", "단톡방"],
  };
  const image = {
    src: [Me, User],
  };
  const content = {
    message: ["나와의 채팅", "안녕 보리야", "오늘 애견운동장 가고싶다!"],
  };
  const time = {
    time: ["어제", "오후 12:03", "오후 04:36"],
  };
  const icons = {
    pin: [Pin, "", Bell],
    bell: [Bell, "", ""],
  };
  const member = {
    num: ["", "", 6],
  };
  return (
    <>
      <ChatsPresenter
        title={title}
        content={content}
        time={time}
        image={image}
        icons={icons}
        member={member}
      />
    </>
  );
};

export default ChatContainer;
```

**Router file**

```
import React from "react";
import {
  HashRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Switch,
  Redirect,
} from "react-router-dom";

import Navgation from "../Components/Navgation";
import StatusBar from "../Components/StatusBar";
import Friends from "../Screens/Friends";
import Chats from "../Screens/Chats";
import News from "../Screens/Shap/News";
import More from "../Screens/More";
import Setting from "../Screens/Setting";
import OpenChat from "../Screens/OpenChat";
import Covid19 from "../Screens/Shap/Covid19";
import KakaoTV from "../Screens/Shap/KakaoTV";
import Entertain from "../Screens/Shap/Entertain";
import Fun from "../Screens/Shap/Fun";
import Sports from "../Screens/Shap/Sports";

const Routers = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <StatusBar />
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" exact component={Friends} />
        <Route path="/chats">
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/chats" component={Chats} />
            <Route path="/chats/openchats" component={OpenChat} />
          </Switch>
        </Route>
        <Route path="/shap">
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/shap/covid19" component={Covid19} />
            <Route path="/shap" component={News} />
            <Route path="/shap/kakaotv" component={KakaoTV} />
            <Route path="/shap/fun" component={Fun} />
            <Route path="/shap/entertain" component={Entertain} />
            <Route path="/shap/sports" component={Sports} />
          </Switch>
        </Route>
        <Route path="/more" component={More} />
        <Route path="/setting" component={Setting} />
        <Redirect from="*" to="/" />
      </Switch>
      <Navgation />
    </Router>
  );
};

export default Routers;
```

First image is file list
[image]

Second image is Screen image[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the issue is at your switch route. React-router-dom will pick the first Route that  has a path that satisfies desired path `/chats/openchats`, but not necessary an exact match. `/chats` satisfies the condition, because any `/chats/something` contains `/chats`.

you can overcome this by passing a `exact` prop to your `Route` component. this way you are explicitly stating that it must be an exact match to this route be picked:

```
<Switch>
  <Route path="/chats" component={Chats} exact />
  <Route path="/chats/openchats" component={OpenChat} />
</Switch>
```